# FLEXBOX LAYOUT: Problems with navigations

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<header class="main-header">
  <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a class="main-navA" href="#">ice cream</a></li>
      <li><a class="main-navA" href="#">donuts</a></li>
      <li><a class="main-navA" href="#">tea</a></li>
      <li><a class="main-navA" href="#">coffee</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
^how i am used to writing html code

<header class="main-header">
        <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
        <div><a class="main-navA" href="#">ice cream</a></div>
        <div><a class="main-navA" href="#">donuts</a></div>
        <div><a class="main-navA" href="#">tea</a></div>
        <div><a class="main-navA" href="#">coffee</a></div>
</header><!--/.main-header-->
```

^the new way i think would make our lives easier.

Do you think it's better to not use UL elements for navs to make it easier to align your flex items with css? Instead of the the li elements maybe use div elements? or do you guys think this is bad because it's not semantic html?

Comment: I always try to avoid using `div` for multiple elements such as menu links.
With CSS you can overwrite every default CSS values. Doesn't matter what you use.

Comment: i feel like it does matter because when i use the the first example i have to make the ul a flex container and justify-content: flex-end it and the links appear overlap each other and when i use the second example its better aligned with the second example i gave @DOCTYPEHTML

Comment: Share your CSS and I will evaluate it. But in general you can overwrite any default CSS rules.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML oh yes youre right i misunderstood your comment english isnt my first language

Answer (score 0):

This is my prefered way, if i dont want to use ul and li's

```
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="main-navA1">ice cream</a>
        <a href="#" class="main-navA2">donuts</a>
        <a href="#" class="main-navA3">tea</a>
        <a href="#" class="main-navA4">coffee</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Still uses div to block things, but clear than list.